# 301 redirect to full path

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a lot incorrect back links, the links are pointing to:

> http://www.domain.com/tags/keyword

while the correct path is

> http://www.domain.com/tags/keyword/

there are hundreds of those...how could i 301 redirect from the wrong links to the correct links?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: well i have tried different options reading other posts about this subject and trying to find the logic but none worked, my knowledge is very very limited..if you can help i would really appreciate it and also if you could explain solution so i can learn a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^tags/([^/]+)$ /tags/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

- `RewriteBase /` tells apache that your URI starts by a `/`. If your site was in a subfolder you should write `RewriteBase /subfolder/` instead.
- `^tags/([^/]+)$`: you search for an URI starting with `tags/` followed by `[^/]+` that means any characters except `/`. The `( )` around it are there to capture it and use it in the redirection. So we capture any characters that are not `/` between `tags/.../` in the URI. (`^` marks the start of the string while `$` marks the end)
- `/tags/$1/` is the redirection. `$1` means the first previous captured element (the one witch was between `( )`).
- `[L,R=301]` indicates to apache that it should stop process other rules and redirect with a 301 header code.

Comment: Perfectly working could please explain so i can learn, appreciated!

Comment: I've added some more explanation ;)

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation also really appreciated to understand better regex