# Azure 301 redirect to a certain path

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create a 301 redirect in MS Azure to specific js script. The redirect rule from this post [Azure Website 301 Redirect - Where Do I Put It?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004077/azure-website-301-redirect-where-do-i-put-it/18005525#18005525) for reidirecting from one domain's home page to another. However, it does not redirect when using full paths.

I have found this post [301 redirect to full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033190/301-redirect-to-full-path) for Apache. Not sure how to implement it for IIS on Azure.

This is what works

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^iistestapp.azurewebsites.net$"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://dev.widget.testdrive.pw/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>  
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is what does not work

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^http://dev.widget.testdrive.pw/integration/integration.js$"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://code.testdrive.pw/vipdrv/vipdrv.min.js{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>  
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The rule should direct the request to https://code.testdrive.pw/vipdrv/vipdrv.min.js and print the script output

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members.

If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it.
We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

iis server variable {HTTP_HOST} only matches the hostname from the URL.

if you want to check another part like folder path and the filename you could use the REQUEST_URI server variable. For example, https://contoso.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret would return /over/there.

so based on your requirement you could try below rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^dev.widget.testdrive.pw$" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/integration/integration.js$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://code.testdrive.pw{C:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

for more information you could refer below links:

[IIS Server Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables)

[Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)